# Android App stopped unexpectedly while trying to call a constructor

Tags: java, android

My Android App just crashes ("...has stopped unexpectedly") and I debugged it so that I know where it crashes:

```
Log.d( "myapp", "note 1" );
try
{
    Bla1 bla = new Bla1();
}
catch( Exception e )
{
    Log.d( "myapp", e.getMessage() );
}
Log.d( "myapp", "note 2" );
```

"note 1" is the last thing printed to the log before the app crashes. I also have a Log.d statement in the Constructor of Bla1 which is obviously never executed.
This code snippet takes place in a method of the class MainActivity (which extends Activity). Bla1 is an inner class of MainActivity and extends the abstract class Bla which is also an inner class of MainActivity.
In logcat these two lines appear:

> E/dalvikvm(20567): Could not find class 'com.tb.myapp.MainActivity$Bla1', referenced from method com.tb.myapp.MainActivity.parseFile
>   E/dalvikvm(20567): Could not find class 'com.tb.myapp.MainActivity$Bla', referenced from method com.tb.myapp.MainActivity$MyTextWatcher.afterTextChanged

So these instances can't be created which then results in:

> E/AndroidRuntime(20567): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20567): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.tb.myapp.MainActivity$Bla1

The code of the 2 inner classes (Bla and Bla1) is here: http://pastebin.com/9hAGdubb

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? I totally don't know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include your logcat, please make sure it includes a stack trace from the crash.

Comment: look in logcat to find the exact line of the exception thrown in Bla1's constructor

Comment: Added some logcat information. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Post the code of both inner classes.  Considering trying a test case where the instantiated inner class does not extend anything else.

Comment: Added the code of the two inner classes Bla and Bla1.

Comment: would making the classes static help you in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve my problem by copying the nested classes into own files and making them "normal" (non-nested) classes. 
Though this is working, it is probably not the best or even a good solution, since there are reasons to make classes nested classes. (See "Why Use Nested Classes?" http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

If anyone figures out another solution, I would appreciate it if you let us know.